# Pattern for deleting items from a Silverlight ItemsControl

Tags: silverlight, xaml, mvvm, observablecollection

I have a Silverlight page that contains an ItemsControl. It looks something like this

```
-- Name             Description          [Add]
-- Thing1           The first thing      [Edit] [Delete]
-- Thing2           The second thing     [Edit] [Delete]
```

where `[Edit]`, `[Delete]`, and `[Add]` are buttons.

Currently I'm binding the control to a collection of `Thing` and using a template to display the properties, and bind to an `Edit` Command in my ViewModel.

It doesn't make sense (to me) for the `ThingViewModel` to have a `Delete` Command which causes it to delete itself;

- doesn't seem clean
- the Thing doesn't know that it is in a collection so can't remove itself from the collection

So what's the best pattern to wire up the `[Delete]` button?

Comment: In WPF this would be easy - I would bind the Delete button to a Delete command in the parent's datacontext using `RelativeSource`. Unfortunately `RelativeSource` in Silverlight seems crippled and half-useless...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I've come up with - in a very simplified form. It's an obvious choice when `RelativeSource` is not available.

- Name a control which binds to the parent / collection
- Specify the `ElementName` property on the binding for the child / item

This works for an `ItemsControl` but I haven't been able to get this pattern to work for a `DataGrid` yet.

```
<ItemsControl Name="MyParentControl"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Things}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="Delete" 
                    Command="{Binding ElementName=MyParentControl, 
                        Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

The "Delete" code will not be run on the ViewModel for the individual item, in the collection, rather it would be bubbled up (somehow) to the ViewModel that contains the collection, and processed there.

Pseudocode:

```
public class ItemContainerViewModel
{
    List<ItemClass> Items { get; set; }

    public void DeleteItem(ItemClass item)
    {
        this.Items.Remove(item);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.Items); // Causes controls bound to this list to refresh their contents
    }
}
```

One way to bubble up the event is to have the ItemViewModel aware of it's parent ViewModel

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public ItemsCollectionViewModel ParentViewModel { get; private set; }
    public ItemViewModel(ItemsCollectionViewModel parentViewModel)
    {
        this.ParentView = parentViewModel;
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        this.ParentViewModel.Delete(this);
    }
}
```

There are better ways with a MVVM framework like Caliburn.Micro or MVVM-Lite, but this at least gets you started on how to think about these kinds of operations in your ViewModel.

Essentialy - your ViewModel should be able to do all of your user operations without requiring a View of any kind. (You should be able to run some test code, and have your VM work as intended without a bound View)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a listbox so that the user can select a row and then put your commands in the VM that contains the collection, you get a cleaner implementation.

here is the xaml for a row with a delete button.  The trick is to bind the button to the parent items DeleteCommand by using "RelativeSource"

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"   >
                                <Label Content="{Binding}" />
                                <Button Content="Delete" Command="{Binding DataContext.MyDeleteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" />
                            </StackPanel >
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

And the ViewModel code

```
public DelegateCommand<object> MyDeleteCommand { get; set; }

protected void DoDelete(object o)
{
    MyItems.Remove(MySelectedItem);
}

protected bool CanDoDelete(object o)
{
    return MySelectedItem != null;
}

string _mySelectedItem;
public string MySelectedItem
{
    get { return _mySelectedItem; }
    set
    {
        _mySelectedItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MySelectedItem");
        MyDeleteCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}

ObservableCollection<string> _myItems;
public ObservableCollection<string> MyItems
{
    get { return _myItems; }
    set 
    { 
        _myItems = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("MyItems");
    }
}
```

oh, i just saw the above comment about silverlight and relativeSource.  I did this with WPF and tested it out, which worked,  it may not work for silverlight

Comment: This is how I would do it in WPF, but there's no `FindAncestor` in Silverlight.